# Разпознать кактинку с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, распознавание-образов, распознавание

На страницу загружается картинка , есть выделенные области , они канвасом вырезаются. Задача - распознать наличие или отсутствие чего либо в вырезанный картинках, за исключением линий, которые могут там быть.

Comment: Не думаю, что кто-то понял ваше задачу. Создайте ,пожалуйста, пример в онлайн редакторе кода или приатачте пример кода в описание.

Comment: @Valera Checha есть скан листа там есть ячейки, одни пустые, в других поставлен крестик, надо определить в каких есть крестик, в каких его нет. области которые надо проверить вырезаются , дабы не проверять всё, при вырезании попадают и границы ячеек

Comment: сформулирую иначе: определить есть ли на картинке рукописные крестик, галочка

Comment: я думаю тут без machine learning не обойтись :(

Comment: @Valera Checha есть что смотреть более детальное? примеры? с чего начать что бы...